# CSS for required fields in Google App Maker

Tags: css, google-app-maker

I am currently working on setting up an input form in Google App Maker.

Some of the textboxes require an input and therefore the labels are tagged with an asterisk (*) when drag them to the page, e.g. "Birthday *".

But when I drag the textboxes into a panel in order to rearrange them, the asterisk keeps disappearing. How can make the asterisk appear again?

Comment: I have tried something like

.asterisk_input:after {
  label: " *";
}

which did not work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it happens?**

Once you drop a form on a page App Maker will add the following CSS classes to form's widgets:

- `app-FormBody` for the inner form panel
- `required` for all input widgets with input required

Also somewhere in App Maker's internals the following CSS rules are defined:

```
/* Show asterisk only for direct children of 'app-FormBody' panel
   marked with 'required' class */
...
.app-FormBody > .app-TextBox.required > .app-TextBox-Label:after,
... {
  content: " *";
}
```

So, when you drop panel inside form body and drag your input inside that inner panel App Maker CSS rules stop working (the widgets are not direct children of `app-FormBody` anymore).

**How to fix it?**

- you can try to override default App Maker styles

```
/* Note: there is no '>' selector */
.app-FormBody .app-TextBox.required > .app-TextBox-Label:after {
  content: " *";
}
```

I'm not sure what side effects it can potentially cause...

- You can explicitly add asterisk in binding

  `@models.MyModel.fields.FieldName.displayName + ' *'`

Please, also keep in mind that App Maker will not automatically add those hidden styles to the widgets you'll add after form is generated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below worked for me, although there might be other ways of doing it too.

Please note: If you will use this only in one page, place the css code at the **Page style** level, otherwise, place it at the **Global style** level.

**CSS:**

```
.customRequired::after {
  content: " *";
}
```

Once you've written the CSS, go to the **onAttach** event of the **TextBox** widget and use the following JS:

```
var elem = widget.getElement();
elem.children[0].classList.add("customRequired");
```

Additional notes: I tried using the appmaker default css class which is **required** but it didn't work. Furthermore, I only tested this on the **TextBox** widget.

Hope it helps!